# Styling Action Bar Overflow Menu background color

Tags: android

So I'm trying to style the action bar overflow menu but am having no luck at all. For some reason, the style I'm trying to apply (white background) is like getting overridden completely somewhere. Any ideas?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App.EditText</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/night</item>
        <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/ListPopupWindow</item>
    </style>


 <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution,

Hope this will help others.

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/11/the-unknown-style-actionbarwidgettheme.html

Basically you need to generate a new theme (style) for `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` which will be used for inflation to properly style the menu items as needed.

```
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidgetTheme</item>


<style name="ActionBarWidgetTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style name="YOUR_DARK_AB_THEME">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/YourActionBarWidget</item>
</style>

<!-- This helps the PopupMenu stick with Light theme while the ActionBar is in Dark theme -->
<style name="YourActionBarWidget"
    parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below lines to change the background of the OverFlow Menu..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Hope it will help you..